# Angular 4: let child affect parent template without ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, runtime-error

I have a simple template in my AppComponent which loads content via the router,
and has an optional footer based on the content loaded into `<router-outlet>`.
The page layout depends on the interaction between the css classes in the rest of this top-level template, so they need to stay together.

```
<div class='fullPageContent'>
    <router-outlet autoscroll></router-outlet>
    <div class='stickyFooterPush'></div>
</div>
<last-revised *ngIf="globalFlag" class='stickyFooter'></last-revised>
```

However setting the "global flag" in the routed-to components causes the dreaded **ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError**.

So, how can each component that the router puts into `<router-outlet>` ***legally*** enable/disable the footer?

Comment: can you create a demo on stackblitz?

Comment: its a really big app which is why i drastically simplified it here...the question is, how in general should a router-outlet child affect the parent? I gather that the ngIf is evaluated before the outlet children get the chance to set/change the flag...so, how *should* they communicate?

Comment: it's hard to reason not seeing the error reproduced. please try creating a demo on stackblitz